# Help adding new property to object literal

Tags: javascript, json, object-literal

Why is this returning:
tracker.paramsToTrack is undefined

```
var tracker = {};
var paramsToTrack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
for (p in paramsToTrack)
{
    if(params[paramsToTrack[p]])
    {
        tracker.paramsToTrack[p] = params[paramsToTrack[p]];
    }

}
console.log(tracker);
```

I'm basically checking params if 'a' through 'e' are present. If so, add them to the tracker object like so:

tracker.a = stuff

tracker.b = stuff

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tracker.paramsToTrack[p]
```

Should probably be

```
tracker[paramsToTrack[p]]
```

Also, and not that you asked, you may want to eliminate the redundant array lookups:

```
var tracker = {};
var paramsToTrack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var paramName;
for (p in paramsToTrack)
{
    paramName = paramsToTrack[p];
    if(params[paramName])
    {
        tracker[paramName] = params[paramName];
    }

}
console.log(tracker);
```

Or better yet, if you are working in a modern Javascript environment:

```
paramsToTrack.forEach(function (paramName) {
    if(params[paramName])
    {
        tracker[paramName] = params[paramName];
    }
});
```

Comment: The dot notation treats the property name literally.  You are essentially asking for the "paramsToTrack" property of tracker.  Really what you want is for the expression paramsToTrack[p] to be evaluated, and then the result to be treated as the property name.

Comment: @Joshua McGinnis: The following two notations are equivalent: `obj['property']` and `obj.property`. You can use variables with the former notation, only.

Comment: @Bobby. Thanks again. Can you explain what you mean by "modern Javascript environment" and explain what you're alternative approach is doing at a high level?

Comment: The latest version of ECMAScript (what we're calling Javascript) is version 5, and among many other things it officially introduced the forEach function for arrays.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.  It's just a more succinct way to iterate over the values of an array.  That way you don't have to create an array index variable (p in this case) -- you can just directly use the array elements.  Since it's the latest version of ECMAScript it's not supported in all browsers natively, hence a modern Javascript environment.